# How do I get typings for styled-components working with ts-loader?

Tags: typescript, webpack, styled-components, ts-loader

I'm using ts-loader with webpack to compile my typescript files. I've been able to get my setup working for all the modules that have typings in the @types module but I can't get it to work with styled-components which supplies its own typings file.

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = function(env) {
  return {
     module: {
        rules: [
           {
              test: /\.jsx?$/,
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              options: {
                 babelrc: false,
                 cacheDirectory: true,
              }
           },
           {
              test: /\.tsx?$/,
              loader: 'ts-loader',
              options: {
                 configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, "tsconfig.json")
              },
           }
        ]
     },
     resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules'],
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
     },
     context: __dirname,
     target: 'web',
  };
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "es5",
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "jsx": "react",
      "allowJs": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
   }
}
```

When I try `import { ThemedStyledFunction } from 'styled-components'`
I get:

```
Module '"node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled- components.browser.es"' has no exported member 'ThemedStyledFunction'
```

I've tried manually importing the typings for styled-components by adding:

```
"files": [
    "node_modules/styled-components/typings/styled-components.d.ts"
],
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I've even tried making a directory under @types called styled-components and copying over the typings to a index.d.ts but I still get this same error.

Comment: It looks like Webpack may be interpreting the `package.json` of `styled-components` incorrectly and looking for the typings in the wrong place.  A hint from [this thread](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/704): if you run `webpack --verbose`, do you get output showing what files Webpack is looking at?

Comment: So here's the relevant output from --verbose   [108] node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.browser.es.js 84.6 kB {36} [depth 1] [built]
        [exports: css, keyframes, injectGlobal, isStyledComponent, consolidateStreamedStyles, ThemeProvider, withTheme, ServerStyleSheet, StyleSheetManager, __DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_HAUNTED_BY_SPOOKY_GHOSTS, default]

Comment: Interestingly enough it doesn't show ThemedStyledFunction in the exports. I'm not sure why. These don't seem to match up with what the typings definition describes either.

Comment: Right, ThemedStyledFunction is an interface, so it doesn't exist in the JavaScript.  It makes sense that Webpack is loading the JavaScript.  The question is why Webpack isn't also loading the TypeScript declaration file.  There should be some additional output showing the processing of the package.json file.  Can you please post it (maybe in the question where there's a higher length limit)?  I've never used Webpack but I might be able to research this from the output.

Comment: I don't see anything like that. All I see is that line to build styled-components and then a bunch of lines that import styled-components. The whole output is just a list of the entry points and then a list of lines exactly like that.

Comment: I am out of ideas.  If you publish a repository that reproduces the problem, I will look.

Comment: This is really strange. I just tried importing ThemedStyledFunction in a sample project I have and ran webpack -- no errors at all. It was able to find the typings file. Maybe also give Awesome-Typescript-Loader a try.